# Massive SMS sender with c# and numbers from database

Tags: c#, android, winforms, sms, firebird

I have office program that I use for my work and there are a lot of partner information into database. One of column is `Mobile Phone`.

What I want to do is make is to connect my android phone to PC, run that office program and from there send one message to all partners from database.

How can I pass message and number to my android and then send sms?

I have read about sms sending from pc but I found something that works only with nokia phones, some programs, and something that is outdated.

My office program is made in c#/winfroms/firebird.

Comment: you can send SMS from your C# application by the implementation of some SMS API. so, there is no need to connect the phone.

Comment: It needs to be phone since I expect receiver to respond to number that I sent from (call or sms)

Comment: in SMS API, you can send sms from predefined number. If you want to keep all converstation in your phone message inbox - connecting your phone and sending all the SMS from your phone messaging application will be the good option.

Comment: you may want to prepare an android app, which always listerns for a specific message. you can trigger a message from your C# to the connected android devices (via adb). this message contains the phone numbers. the android application process the received message, and send SMS to the parsed numbers.

Comment: How can I achieve sending 2 strings from pc to android (1 is message, second is numbers which will I handle at android)

Comment: use JSON string.

Comment: I know that but I do not know how to make connection between android and pc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154032/discussion-between-banee-ishaque-k-and-aleksa-ristic).

Answer (score 0):

You have to write an api (Connection to users database and hande sending sms) with mvc and c# then you can write simple app in Android studio  to send message to your api(with retrofit2 library). If you want more help. I can write some sudo code here.
If You have to send SMS by cell phone, you can get list of number by an api

MVC Api Controller to get Target Numbers from android:

```
public class SmsUsersController : ApiController
{
    private Context db = new Context();

    // GET: api/SmsUsers
    public IQueryable<SmsUser> GetSmsUsers()
    {
        return db.SmsUsers;
    }
}
```

and use retrofit to read api values:
http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: That is what I started considering but do not know how to achieve sending data from pc program(winfrom) to android app. Data I need to send is 2 strings only and everything else I will handle in android app

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a sms gateway can help you, https://github.com/ushahidi/SMSSync